# Spark SQL exception handling

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, error-handling, apache-spark-sql

In order to handle Spark exception on RDD operations I can use the following approach with additional `exceptions` column:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...

val rddWithExcep = df.rdd.map { row: Row =>
  val memberIdStr = row.getAs[String]("member_id")
  val memberIdInt = Try(memberIdStr.toInt) match {
    case Success(integer) => List(integer, null)
    case Failure(ex) => List(null, ex.toString)
  }
  Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq.toList ++ memberIdInt)
}

val castWithExceptionSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("member_id_int", IntegerType, true)
  , StructField("exceptions", StringType, true)))

val castExcepDf = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddWithExcep, castWithExceptionSchema)

castExcepDf.printSchema()
castExcepDf.show()
```

Is it possible to handle such exception on Spark SQL? For example, currently in case of any errors, Spark SQL simply returns `null` value and hides the error.

For example division by 0 will be resulted into `null` value and not into an error..
**In my opinion - this is a very serious issue in Spark SQL because it can simple produces unexpected/wrong data that you won't even notice.**

Is it possible to override this behavior and let Spark fail with an appropriate detailed exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spark 3.0, you can set property `spark.sql.ansi.enabled` to `true` in your spark session to throw exception and stop spark execution instead of saving `null` value in column. However, failure will be global and not on row per row basis. See [ANSI Compliance page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html) on Spark's documentation website for more details.

So the following code snippet:

```scala
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.ansi.enabled", "true")

Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("MyCol")
  .withColumn("divideByZero", col("MyCol") / 0)
  .show(false)
```

throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkArithmeticException: divide by zero
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.divideByZeroError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.DivModLike.eval(arithmetic.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.DivModLike.eval$(arithmetic.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Divide.eval(arithmetic.scala:534)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(InterpretedMutableProjection.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$43.$anonfun$applyOrElse$80(Optimizer.scala:1840)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$43.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1840)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$43.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1835)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1835)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1833)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertOptimized(QueryExecution.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCteMap(QueryExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainString(QueryExecution.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
    ...
```